# redirect orginal url to rewrite url (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to redirect original url to rewrite url

orginal :
domain/index.php?p=50
rewrite :
domain/post/50/

I try to explain better here

iF

**Request : domain/index.php?p=50**

**redirect to : domain/post/50/**

**rewritten to :domain/index.php?p=50**

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

You must think in the other way :

- User will use domain/post/50
- I will rewrite this url to domain/index.php?p=50